# Pool and Manager in multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, python-multiprocessing, pool

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager


def test(num):
    queue.put(num)


queue = Manager().Queue()
pool = Pool(5)

for i in range(30):
    pool.apply_async(test, (i, ))

pool.close()
pool.join()

print(queue.qsize())
```

The output of the code above is 30. However, if line 8 is exchanged with line 9 (see the code below), the output will be 0. So is there anybody who knows why? Thank you!

```
 from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager


 def test(num):
   queue.put(num)


 pool = Pool(5)
 queue = Manager().Queue()

for i in range(30):
    pool.apply_async(test, (i, ))

pool.close()
pool.join()

print(queue.qsize())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens due to fact that you are sharing queue via globals. So if you do pool init with queue already created it shares the same Queue, otherwise not. Add `print globals()` to test method and you will see difference.

Nevertheless, it's better to pass queue to pool as method param to be sure that it's "the same" object.

```
def test(num, q):
    q.put(num)

def main():
    pool = Pool(5)
    q = Manager().Queue()

    for i in range(30):
        pool.apply_async(test, (i, q))

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print(q.qsize())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`Output: 30`